# Hide one item from menu on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap to build a menu. When the page is resized for small screens I get my hamburger icon and it shows all items in the menu. Is there a way to hide one item from that menu? I don't want my Cart to show up under the hamburger. I could write some jQuery code myself to do that, but I am wondering if Bootstrap already has a way to do that?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navMain" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navMain"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-lg"> <span class="sr-only">Shopping Cart</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a> </div>
        <!-- end navbar-header -->

        <div id="navMain" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <div class="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Cart </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Account <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>
                                <div class="row" style="width: 400px;">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-3" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-3" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Option X <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Option Y <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Option Z</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end navMain --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end container-fluid --> 
</nav>
<!-- end container-fluid --> 

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== --> 
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster --> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug --> 
<script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's pretty easy if you use the [Bootstrap responsive utility classes `hidden-*`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) classes. In your case, add `hidden-xs` to the button.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-lg hidden-xs">
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/44PQOE3vg1

Comment: I meant to ask how to hide Cart from the hamburger menu, but your answer works, I just applied it to `<li class="dropdown hidden-xs">`. Nice to know about the hidden-xs class.

Comment: @tuco I tried to use the solution for my <li> element, but nothing has changed for me. My <li> nav item is stil visible, also on a small device. Any ideas?