# Hide menu items on mobile bootstrap nav

Tags: html, css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got this nav element on my webpage header:

```
<div id="categorymenu">
  <nav class="subnav">
    <ul class="nav-pills categorymenu container">
      <li> <a class="home" href="index.php"><span> Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a id='info' href='info.php'>Info</a>
         <div>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="info.php#step1">About it</a> </li>
              <li><a href="info.php#step2">How to</a> </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I would like to hide the 2 internal `<li>` elements (the submenu of my menu) when running on mobile.

As mentioned here: [Hide one item from menu on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027497/hide-one-item-from-menu-on-mobile) I tried to add this class to the 2 `<li>` elements:

```
...
<li><a class="dropdown hidden-xs" href="info.php#step1">About it</a> </li>
<li><a class="dropdown hidden-xs" href="info.php#step2">How to</a> </li>
...
```

but still nothing happens on small devices: the entire menu is always visible.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using Bootstrap? if no then it's will do by Media query.

Comment: Yes, bootstrap3 as tagged.

Comment: Please post a [Bootply](http://bootply.com) demo to replicate your issue.

Comment: i think you got issue on loading bootstrap files see my answer @kiks73

Comment: Thanks to everybody, it seems a "problem" with js customization of my php theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my PHP HTML/CSS theme. There is a custom.js file that manage the mobile menu.

I post the solution that I've found because I think that's pretty common to use this kinds of PHP HTML/CSS themes.

First of all I add the class for hidden-xs to the anchor element:

```
<li><a class="hidden-xs" href="info.php#step1">About it</a></li>
<li><a class="hidden-xs" href="info.php#step2">How to</a></li>
```

Then i changed the custom.js of the theme adding the `.not('.hidden-xs')` on the row after the `// Populate dropdown with menu items` comment

```
// Category Menu mobile
 $("<select />").appendTo("nav.subnav");

 // Create default option "Go to..."
  $("<option />", {
     "selected": "selected",
     "value"   : "",
     "text"    : "Go to..."
  }).appendTo("nav.subnav select");

// Populate dropdown with menu items
  $("nav.subnav a[href]").not('.hidden-xs').each(function() {
   var el = $(this);
   $("<option />", {
       "value"   : el.attr("href"),
       "text"    : el.text()
   }).appendTo("nav.subnav select");
  });

 // To make dropdown actually work
   // To make more unobtrusive: http://css-tricks.com/4064-unobtrusive-page-changer/
  $("nav.subnav select").change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Media Queries?
http://jsfiddle.net/geargio72/0kb8ecea/

```
<div id="categorymenu">
  <nav class="subnav">
    <ul class="nav-pills categorymenu container">
  <li> <a class="home" href="index.php"><span> Home</span></a></li>
  <li><a id='info' href='info.php'>Info</a>
     <div>
        <ul class="rowHide">
          <li><a href="info.php#step1">About it</a> </li>
          <li><a href="info.php#step2">How to</a> </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>


 @media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 765px) 
{
  .rowHide { display: none; }  
 }
```

Comment: He is also using Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

See this it will give you idea...

Without using media query...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <!-- Le styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />



</head>

<body>



  <div id="categorymenu">
    <nav class="subnav">
      <ul class="nav-pills categorymenu container">
        <li> <a class="home" href="index.php"><span> Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a id='info' href='info.php'>Info</a>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="hidden-xs" href="info.php#step1">About it</a> 
              </li>
              <li><a class="hidden-xs" href="info.php#step2">How to</a> 
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```